# Git: file handling, sources vs. output

Tags: git

I have a question about Git and the best strategy to handle source-files vs. output-files (a file that is rebuildable with the sources).

Lets say I have some source-files and also some output-files (e.g. the product of a compiler; generated makefiles).

Normally I would say I only want to have the sources in my repo.

Today I see the following ways to handle it.

**a)** Manually pick every sourcefile with git-add. But thats a lot of work compared to git-add *.

**b)** Go easy and git-add anything (. or *). But then the sources are in the repo too. Also possible to have a modified file but no source changed (e.g. a output-file with a timestamp included).

**c)** Set .gitinore to exclude output-files. That can be also some work because in some project there are a lot of different forms of them.

**d)** Set .gitignore to ignore all but whiltelist the sources. I think thats less work than §c. But with the danger to miss something if not on the watch.

So what do you think is the best way OR a common strategy?
Thanks!

Chris

Comment: The usual solution would be **c**, to exclude all files that can be generated from the source. It may help if you can set up your build process to generate those files into certain subdirectories, or append some suffix (e.g. `.generated.ext`) which you can then use to set up filters.

Comment: Only 2 share their strategy??

Comment: This question is actually off topic because it is asking for an opinion. In general, you can do whatever you feel comfortable with, it doesn’t really matter as long as you and your team feel productive with it.

Answer (score 1):

a.

Its a one time activity.

Its extremely simplified if your build system has a clean option.

Comment: Are you sure you mean *a*, to add every source file manually (which you would have to redo with every change)?

Comment: I personally have done this for as long as I can remember. Its only a headache when you're moving a project to git first time. After that only newly created files have to be added, which doesn't happen very often (at least for me). I also realize this question is more of "whats your opinion" type, and so may be off-topic for SO.

Comment: That’s certainly an interesting way to approach this! Totally fine if it works for you :) I personally prefer maintaining a good ignore list instead.